# FBFinalClassViolationException: FBAdTimer is a final class and cannot be subclassed

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook

We've upgraded to FBAudienceNetwork v.4.26, and now we're seeing the following unhandled runtime exception any time we try to run our unit tests target in  Xcode:

```
2017-10-12 15:30:41.229388-0500 App[60509:1890366] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'FBFinalClassViolationException', reason: 'FBAdTimer is a final class and cannot be subclassed. FBAdTimer'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000011ca991cb __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000011c1bef41 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   AppTests                    0x00000001399cc669 +[FBAdTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:repeats:block:] + 0
    3   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000011c1bfa14 CALLING_SOME_+initialize_METHOD + 19
    4   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000011c1bfdae _class_initialize + 276
    5   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000011c1c65e7 lookUpImpOrForward + 225
    6   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000011c1d63d4 _objc_msgSend_uncached + 68
    7   AppTests                    0x00000001399c8ec4 +[FBAdFingerprinter load] + 46
    8   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000011c1c069b call_load_methods + 695
    9   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000011c1c12f3 load_images + 70
    10  ???                                 0x000000010ff7adac 0x0 + 4562857388
    11  ???                                 0x000000010ff876c5 0x0 + 4562908869
    12  ???                                 0x000000010ff86898 0x0 + 4562905240
    13  ???                                 0x000000010ff8692c 0x0 + 4562905388
    14  ???                                 0x000000010ff7d956 0x0 + 4562868566
    15  ???                                 0x000000010ff83076 0x0 + 4562890870
    16  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000011ddeba47 dlopen + 86
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x000000011ca49808 _CFBundleDlfcnLoadBundle + 152
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x000000011ca49694 _CFBundleLoadExecutableAndReturnError + 324
    19  Foundation                          0x0000000114060ec1 -[NSBundle loadAndReturnError:] + 520
    20  IDEBundleInjection                  0x0000000110057860 __XCBundleInjection + 798
    21  ???                                 0x000000010ff8bc16 0x0 + 4562926614
    22  ???                                 0x000000010ff8be46 0x0 + 4562927174
    23  ???                                 0x000000010ff876da 0x0 + 4562908890
    24  ???                                 0x000000010ff86898 0x0 + 4562905240
    25  ???                                 0x000000010ff8692c 0x0 + 4562905388
    26  ???                                 0x000000010ff7b15d 0x0 + 4562858333
    27  ???                                 0x000000010ff7ec98 0x0 + 4562873496
    28  ???                                 0x000000010ff7a3d4 0x0 + 4562854868
    29  ???                                 0x0000000118742510 0x0 + 4705232144
    30  ???                                 0x0000000118740a39 0x0 + 4705225273
    31  ???                                 0x000000011873c249 0x0 + 4705206857
    32  ???                                 0x000000011873c036 0x0 + 4705206326
    33  ???                                 0x0000000000000007 0x0 + 7
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Curiously enough, within our codebase (including all the third-party dependencies), the only file that *contains* the word "FBAdTimer" is:

```
λ ~/Projects/iOS/app/ IOS-6370* grep -iR "FBAdTimer" .
Binary file ./Pods/FBAudienceNetwork/FBAudienceNetwork.framework/FBAudienceNetwork matches
Binary file ./App.xcworkspace/xcuserdata/silver.xcuserdatad/UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate matches
```

Answer (score 3):

According to https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/147221075773612/, FBAudienceNetwork cannot be in both the test target and the main bundle that loads with it. The solution is to remove the dependency from the test target in Podfile:

```
target 'App' do
  use_frameworks!

  pod 'FBAudienceNetwork'  # Only present in the main app target
end

target 'AppTests' do

end
```

Answer (score 0):

just quoting my case which drive me to visit this thread,

i was creating a framework to manage Facebook Audience Network, i got `FBFinalClassViolationException` Exception many times, on different classes from the package of FacebookAudienceNetwork.framework

the suspect was: [appoDeal](https://appodeal.com/) (is a Mediation Adapter sdk), which was adding the FacebookAudience Network framework to manage their mediation adapter.

removing FacebookAudienceNetwork pod from AppoDeal pod collection solved my issue, (in my case it was okey to remove AppoDeal)

`Hint to Solution:` please check is som other framework/library/sdks adding the FacebookAudienceNetwork

Answer (score 0):

For people who are facing them, simply go to Assets-> Play Services Resolver (or External Dependency Manager)-> iOS Resolver-> Settings and check the checkbox that says "Link Frameworks Statically" this will add an additional information to your Podfile and fixes the Exception that causes crash.

In addition to this solution, another thing causes the same problem. That occurs when FBAudienceNetwork framework is on both Unity-iPhone and Unity-iPhone Tests targets in your Xcode project's Podfile. If this is the case, simply delete the line on the Tests and run "pod install" command on terminal in that directory.