# FBAudience Network as a Framework Integration

Tags: xcode, frameworks, adapter, fbaudience

I'm Integrating Facebook Audience Network for Interstitial and Rewarded types of Ads.

I'm trying to integrate it as a framework and not in the project.

When I'm trying to test it through the Test Cases It failing after this line:

```
self.fbInterstitialAd = [[FBInterstitialAd alloc] initWithPlacementID:self.placementID];
```

and giving me this error:

`*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'FBFinalClassViolationException', reason: 'FBAdConfigManager is a final class and cannot be subclassed. FBAdConfigManager' ***`

I really do not understand why it is crashing. I am really not able to find what is the issue.
I also integrated this Audience network SDK in separate single view Application, there I'm able to see the ADs and working fine.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [FBFinalClassViolationException: FBAdTimer is a final class and cannot be subclassed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46718482/fbfinalclassviolationexception-fbadtimer-is-a-final-class-and-cannot-be-subclas)

Comment: did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and found solution in case of using cocoapods.

change this line in Podfile

```
use_frameworks!
```

to

```
use_frameworks! :linkage => :static
```

I think this crash is caused by framework bug with dynamic linkage.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @sudekon I was also able to fix the problem. This is the only solution which has worked for me.

In addition to what sudekon says, for Unity developers, you can click Assets -> Play Services Resolver (or External Dependency Manager) -> iOS Resolver -> Settings and check the checkbox that says "Link frameworks statically" and then build Xcode project. This will prepare the Podfile with the suggested instructions.

Answer (score -1):

Had the same issue in the past. I was integrating FBAudienceNetwork as a dependency pod in a framework, and the only working solution is to add it manually (drag and drop) to the project not via cocoapods.

Comment: i was also creating a framework for FaceBook Audience Network, faced the same error, but your suggestion didnt work for me! do u know is there anything i have to try?